# Computing the intersection area of two disks in 3D

Tags: regions, geometry, computational-geometry, vector-calculus

Closely related to this question about highlighting [intersection of two disks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104919/52181), I am trying to figure out if one can do so similarly for disks embedded in $3D$ (e.g. in a bounding box). The difference is that, in $3D$ the orientation of the disks matters in how much of overlap/orthogonal-projection there is between them. The orientation of a disk is simply the vector normal to its surface and centered at its center. Therefore, each disk has a center vector (for its position) $\mathbf v$ and a normal vector $\mathbf n$ for its orientation. As an example, 2 disks $i,j$ have maximal overlap if $\mathbf n_i \parallel \mathbf n_j$ *and* the difference vector of their center positions $\mathbf v_j-\mathbf v_i$ also being parallel to their normal, then the overlap area is exactly $\pi r^2,$ $r$ being the radius of the disks.

Intuitively, computing such projection is as if we computed the *shadow* two drawn particles (here disks) create onto one another when visualizing them.

- But is there a way we can quantify the overlap area between two $3D$-embedded disks in Mathematica? Can `RegionIntersection` be made use of for such application?

---

*Additional clarifications after comments:*

To clarify how the overlap between the disks is defined or at least what I mean by it, the idea is to compute the orthogonal projection of their respective surfaces onto one another. For instance given $2$ disks $i,j$ with their position and normal vectors $\mathbf v_i,\mathbf n_i$ and $\mathbf v_j,\mathbf n_j$, we can take the average of the orthogonal-surface-projection of disk $i$ onto plane of disk $j$ with that of disk $j$ onto plane of disk $i$ which yields a symmetrized definition of overlap or intersection between the disks, taking into account not only their orientations but also relative positions.

---

Stealing from [J. M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m-will-be-back-soon)'s [answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/169418/52181) (its first part), here's an image of one such disk within its plane and its orientation vector visualised (the normal to the plane centered at center of disk):

[image: circle on a tilted plane]

---

An attempt to visualize DaveH's [suggestion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/210314/52181) which was very briefly put in their answer:

Say we have one disk centered at `v1` and with normal vector `n1` and another with `v2,n2` as given by (both with diameter `d`):

```
v1 = {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}
n1 = {1, 1, 1}
v2 = {1, 1.5, 0}
n2 = {1, 1, 0}
d = 4
```

then we create cylinders out of the disks, with end-points of each ceylinder given by  $\pm 5 \mathbf n_i$ to respective center position of disk $i$:

```
cyl1 = Cylinder[{v1 - 5*n1, v1 + 5*n1}, d/2]
cyl2 = Cylinder[{v2 - 5*n2, v2 + 5*n2}, d/2]
```

and visualizing `Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], cyl1, cyl2}]`:

[image]

But I don't know how much this approach helps in *computing* the overlap area of interest (and if computationally feasible).

Comment: This requires a precise definition of "intersection area" that is more general than the given example.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Good point! Sorry I was a bit unclear about this in my OP. What I meant is in essence: the orthogonal projection of a surface onto a plane. In this case, the surface is that of one of the two disks, and the plane is the plane of the other disk (the plane in which its surface lies). For related example, [here in math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2836878/306321) the case of projecting the surface of a doughnut onto a plane is discussed, in our case it is always 2D disks in $3D.$ I hope this clarifies the aim of the question.

Comment: Hmm. So this notion of intersection are is not symmetric in the two disks?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher It should be ultimately (to get the desired overlap quantification described in the OP). So I figure, by taking the product of the projection of disk $i$ onto plane of disk $j$ with that of disk $j$ onto plane of disk $i$ will yield a symmetrized intersection area definition.

Comment: Maybe you want to the the average of the two areas instead of the product. Otherwise, your "area" scales in an odd way and has the wrong unit ($\mathrm{m}^4$ instead of $\mathrm{m}^2$).

Comment: You need also a perspective and a view point to see such intersections.

Comment: @Cesareo Hi, does that mean there's no objective definition for the projection of one disk's surface onto the other in general? in contrast to the orthogonal projection of vectors onto one another.

Comment: I understood the problem as an occlusion between objects or of a projected shadow of a disk over the other. In this case a point of view or a light source and a perspective are required.

Comment: @Cesareo Ah I see! I think I shouldn't have used the term *shadow* in my OP altogether. What I really meant, as also discussed a bit with Henrik, is the orthogonal projection of one surface onto the other, in order to quantify the overlap between them. So if we can compute the projection of one disk (given its position and orientation vectors) onto the plane of the other, and vice-versa, then we can take the average between the two obtained projected surfaces as their overlap. I hope this helps a bit to clarifty the intent.

Comment: OK. Now I understood the real problem. Thanks.

Comment: @user929304 You are essentially asking for a formula for the intersection area between a disk and an ellipse. To get an idea what kind of cases have to be differentiated can be seen [here](https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/AreaIntersectingEllipses.pdf). For specific cases Mathematica can compute specific values for you, e.g. `Area@RegionIntersection[Disk[], Disk[{1/10, 3/10}, {2, 1/3}]]`. Solving the general case in algebraic form is not so straightforward and would produce a quite big and messy expression.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke Hi, thanks for the input! Indeed I am mainly interested in specific cases and not looking for a general algebraic solution. Basically, my disks (or circles) are embedded in $3D$ so I have to describe them with a center vector+radius+orientation vector (normal $\mathbf n$), unlike circles in $2D.$ But I don't know how to represent them in Mathematica to be able to make use of `RegionIntersection` in order to find the intersection between surfaces of 2 given disks if projected onto one another.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Hi, I hope Im not bothering at a bad time. I wanted to ask you sth regarding Thies' solution below: I'm struggling to figure out how I can extend that method to non-unit disks and box dimensions. Admittedly, his coding is rather terse for me, so maybe I'm missing something obvious... Thanks for any feedback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my take on solving it algebraically:

```
DiskRadius[Disk3D[_, _, radius_]] := radius;
RotateZToNormal[Disk3D[_, n_, _]] := RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, n}];
MoveToDiskCenter[Disk3D[p_, _, _]] := TranslationTransform[p];
TransformUnitDiskTo[d_Disk3D] := RightComposition[RotateZToNormal[d], MoveToDiskCenter[d]]
Project2D = Most;(*leave out z component to project into 2D*)
CartesianFromPolar = (# /. {r -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], \[Phi] -> ArcTan[x, y]} &);
UnitDiskToProjectedEllipseTransform[to_Disk3D] := Function[from, 
  Composition[
    AffineTransform[Reverse[##]] &, (*construct 2d affine transform unitdisk -> projected disk/ellipse*)
    CoefficientArrays[#, {x, y}] &, (*extract 2d ellipse linear transformation coefficients*)
    Simplify, CartesianFromPolar, Project2D,
    InverseFunction[TransformUnitDiskTo[to]],
    TransformUnitDiskTo[from]
  ][r {Cos[\[Phi]], Sin[\[Phi]], 0}]
]
ProjectDiskOnto[to_Disk3D] := Function[from, 
  Composition[
    #.# <= DiskRadius[from]^2 &, 
    InverseFunction[UnitDiskToProjectedEllipseTransform[to][from]]
  ][{x, y}]
]
ProjectedDiskRegion[to_Disk3D] := Function[from, 
  RegionIntersection[
    (ImplicitRegion[#, {x, y}] & @* ProjectDiskOnto[to]) /@ {to, from}
  ]
]
DiskIntersectionArea[disk1_Disk3D, disk2_Disk3D] := 
  Mean[Area /@ {ProjectedDiskRegion[disk1][disk2], 
                ProjectedDiskRegion[disk2][disk1]}]
```

Let's have a look at an example:

```
d1 = Disk3D[{-2, 3, -3}, {2, -3, 6}/7, 1]
d2 = Disk3D[{-1, 1, 1}, {-1, 2, -2}/3, 4/5]
```

Here we encoded the disks by their center point, their normal and their radius with a custom `Disk3D` head.
We can plot these to get an idea

```
PlotDisk3D[d_Disk3D] := ParametricPlot3D[
  TransformUnitDiskTo[d][r {Cos[\[Phi]], Sin[\[Phi]], 0}],
  {r, 0, DiskRadius[d]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Mesh -> None
]
Show[PlotDisk3D /@ {d1, d2}]
```

[image: Plot of both disks together in 3D]

The idea of the solution is to first get an implicit 2d equation of each disk transformed into the reference frame of the other disk and then project it into the xy plane. We do that by creating the function `TransformUnitDiskTo` which produces an `AffineTransform` that would transform a unit disk sitting in the xy-plane into any given `to` disk. Next we start with a parametric polar representation of a unit disk, which we first transform into our (`from`) disk which we want to project, and then follow it by an inverse affine transform to get it into the reference frame of our `to` disk. In this reference frame we can project it into 2D and after that convert back to cartesian coordinates and into an implicit representation instead of parametric. Our two example disks in the other reference frame now look like this:

```
ProjectDiskOnto[d1][d2]
```

$$\left(\frac{43 x}{52}-\frac{8 y}{13}+\frac{1}{4}\right)^2+\left(\frac{37 x}{65}+\frac{11 y}{13}+\frac{1}{5}\right)^2\leq \frac{16}{25}$$

```
ProjectDiskOnto[d2][d1]
```

$$\left(\frac{11 x}{13}-\frac{8 y}{13}+\frac{18}{13}\right)^2+\left(\frac{37 x}{65}+\frac{43 y}{52}-\frac{47}{65}\right)^2\leq 1$$

Projecting a disk onto itself naturally always gives back the disk unaltered:

```
ProjectDiskOnto[d1][d1]
```

$$x^2+y^2\leq 1$$

```
ProjectDiskOnto[d2][d2]
```

$$x^2+y^2\leq \frac{16}{25}$$

Now we can perform the region intersection inside `ImplicitRegion`s

[image: Resulting projected and intersected disk regions.]

and finally take the average of the `Region` `Area`s, which Mathematica happily performs for us symbolically and we end up with an exact expression, which we can either simplify a bit via `RootReduce` on the algebraic parts or just get a numeric approximation with desired accuracy:

```
DiskIntersectionArea[d1, d2] // N
(* 0.9875 *)
```

## Update

- Added support for arbitrary disk radii.
- Fixed a bug in the construction of the implicit ellipse representation.

Comment: I like this solution a lot.

Comment: @user929304 i) this is true when our disk normal is `{0,0,1}`. Generally the projection always happens along the disk normal, which means you have to translate a disk along the other disks normal to keep the projected area constant. ii) No, it should be easily possible to extend it to disks with radii different from one. I'll try to expand the code when i have a bit more free time.

Comment: @user929304 iii) I think mainly you need to be consistent with your units. That means you either could convert the radius into the same unnormalized units as you use for positions and multiply the resulting area with your normalization factor^2, or you could scale your unnormalized positions to 'real' position units before you feed it to the area calculation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update Thies! This indeed seems to work really well and results are in agreement with e.g. Henrik's approach. There are sometimes cases where the algorithm pauses longer than usual and returns a non-numeric result, e.g. with this example: `d1test = Disk3D[{-148.523, -19.2954, 142.73}, {0.696493, -0.319583, -0.642467}, 12.5]; d2test = Disk3D[{148.239, -43.1213, -149.823}, {-0.415674, 0.313735, 0.85369}, 12.5]; DiskIntersectionArea[d1test, d2test] // N` Do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: @user929304 Oh, thanks for pointing that out, the code wasn't robust enough to handle the empty `RegionIntersection` case. I updated `ProjectedDiskRegion` to support those cases properly, so now it should return `EmptyRegion[2]` instead and `DiskIntersectionArea` returns `0` in those cases.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke Thanks very much! I wonder, the speed bottleneck if I m not mistaken stems from the use of `RegionIntersection`, is there a way to obtain the intersection area without the use of the latter?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this function does the trick:

```
F[{p1_, n1_, r1_}, {p2_, n2_, r2_}] := 
 Block[{A1, A2, v, w1, w2, area1, area2, angle}, 
  A1 = Orthogonalize[Join[{n1}, IdentityMatrix[3]]][[2 ;; 3]];
  A2 = Orthogonalize[Join[{n2}, IdentityMatrix[3]]][[2 ;; 3]];
  angle = Min[VectorAngle[n1, n2], VectorAngle[n1, -n2]];
  If[angle < 1. 10^-12,
   {w1, w2} = r1 IdentityMatrix[2]
   ,
   v = r1 Normalize@Cross[n1, n2];
   w1 = A2.v;
   w2 = A2.Cross[n1, v];
   ];
  area1 = Area@RegionIntersection[
     Ellipsoid[A2.(p1 - p2), KroneckerProduct[w1, w1] + KroneckerProduct[w2, w2]],
     Disk[{0, 0}, r2]
     ];
  If[angle < 1. 10^-12,
   {w1, w2} = r2 IdentityMatrix[2]
   ,
   v = r2 Normalize@Cross[n2, n1];
   w1 = A1.v;
   w2 = A1.Cross[n2, v];
   ];
  area2 = Area@RegionIntersection[
     Ellipsoid[A1.(p2 - p1), KroneckerProduct[w1, w1] + KroneckerProduct[w2, w2]],
     Disk[{0, 0}, r1]
     ];
  (area1 + area2)/2
  ]
```

The procedure works like this:

First, we compute two linear projections `A1` and `A2` onto the plane, one with nullspace spanned by the normal `n1`, the other spanned by the normal `n2` (and each projections is isometric in the orthogonal complement of its  nullspace).

For defining an `Ellipsoid`, it suffices to know its center and its covariance matrix. The latter can then be obtained from the sum of the Kronecker products of the half-axis vectors. And half-axis vectors (`w1` and `w2`) can be computed as in the code above.

After having projected everything into the 2D-plane, we can simply apply `RegionIntersection` and `Area`. Here, the intersection and its area are computed numerically, which might make this a rather slow approach (if you have to run this computation a zillion times). Maybe the intersection area for a `Disk` and a general `Ellipsoid` can be computed symbolically and offline? Then one can make this faster. But I don't really know how to so that. Maybe [this](https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/AreaIntersectingEllipses.pdf) might help.

## Edit

I have updated the code above to treat the cases when `n1` and `n2` are almost parallel in a different way. I have not tested it for correctness and for robustness, yet. So use it with caution.

Comment: Many thanks Henrik, this seems to work out quite well and I really like your approach! I'm gonna try it on a set of different examples and get back to you! Quick question, so `r1, r2` are here our diameters right? in case (though happens rarely) the normals are parallel or exactly the same the algorithm has an exception as `v` becomes zero. But slightly nudging one component fixes it (so e.g. `n1=n2={1, 1, 0};` crashes but `n1={1, 1, 0};` and `n2={0.99, 1, 0};` is sufficient to workaround it.

Comment: `r1` and `r1` are of course the **r**adii. ;) Yeah, one certainly has to work out some degenerate cases. However, that's quite simple: If `n1` and `n2` are almost parallel or antiparallel, you may choose `{w1, w2} = r1 IdentityMatrix[2]` and `{w1, w2} = r2 IdentityMatrix[2]`. Notice also that I assumed the normals `n1` and `n2` to be normalized. If your input vectors are not normalized, just normalize them with `Normalize`.

Comment: The w-vectors are the half-axis vectors of the ellipsoid that is created by projection one circle onto the plain of the orther (and than projected to $\mathbb{R}^2$ via the appropriate A-matrix). If the planes of the circles are parallel, then this ellipsoid is a round circle and actually every two vectors that are orthogonal to each other and have the approriate length may serve as w-vectors.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me so promptly, and for the edit (I've tested it, works well ;) )! Just to sanity check my understanding, here are my grouped thoughts **1)** to find the projected circle (ellipsoid), the diameters of the circle are projected onto the diameters of the ellipsoid. **2)** To find the large axis vector of the corresponding ellipsoid, we have to find the vector along the principal line of the plane of `n2` at which the two planes intersect, therefore, the large diameter of the ellipsoid has the same length as the diameter of the circle. The intersection line of the(..)

Comment: is by definition orthogonal to both normal vectors (because it belongs to both planes), thus $\mathbf w_1 \propto \mathbf n_1 \times \mathbf n_2.$ **3)** then comes the minor axis vector $\mathbf w_2$, which is $\perp \mathbf w_1,$ and it must be perpendicular to $\mathbf n_2$ because it lies in the plane to which $\mathbf n_2$ is normal. So I would have thought, $\mathbf w_2 \propto \mathbf n_2\times \mathbf v,$ instead we used (?) $ \propto \mathbf n_1 \times \mathbf v $ which I don't get yet :/ **4)** Once `w1, w2` computed, we collapse them to 2D and (...)

Comment: decompose them in an orthonormal basis (here `A2` because we're considering the projection onto plane of `n2`). **5)** with the 2D axis vectors, we build the covariance matrix whose eigenvalues and eigenvectors are the radii of the ellipsoid and their orientations in the plane respectively.  **6)** Finally, we place the disk which belonged to the plane of `n2` at the origin, and the projected disk (the ellipsoid) has its centred displaced by the difference vector `p1-p2` from the origin. And the intersection area is numerically computed. (...)

Comment: Have I come close to getting the key ideas? where did I go wrong in trying to figure out how `w2` should be calculated in **3)**? thanks a lot in advance again for all your continued feedback! And sorry for the verbose flesh out, I'm really bad at visualising these things in my head.

Comment: Everything is correct. Yes, $w_2$ (before projecting it onto $\mathbb{R}^2$ has to be parallel to $n_2 \times v$. But, in order to get the correct length, I project $n_1 \times v$ directly onto $\mathbb{R}^2$. By the construction of $v$, this is parallel to the projection of $n_2 \times v$ into the plane, but scaled by $\cos(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $n_1$ and $n_2$.

Comment: Of course, you can just rotate $w_1$ by 90 degrees and multiply with $\cos(\theta)$ or use your construction (multiplied with $\cos(\theta)$). The result should be always the same (up to sign, but signs do not matter here).

Comment: Well, there must be working algorithms to determine the intersection points of two ellipsoids. And the intersection area can in principle be determined from these intersection point by elliptic integrals. But that feels a bit too complicated. So do it only if you have to compute thousands of such intersections...

Comment: Thanks for the bounty btw.

Comment: You're welcome :D, btw I have also compared with Thies' approach, results seem to be in agreement. I was wondering, are the native parallelizations that are provided by Mathematica, like `Parallelize[]` relevant for speeding up our `Area@RegionIntersection` step? As in, if we had access to 10 cores instead of say 4, would that be helpful in speeding up our evaluation of the intersection?

Comment: Cannot tell, have never tried more than 4 cores. And my general experience with `Parallelize ` were rather disillusioning. But it _might_ might.

Comment: Tried it on RegionIntersection and it cannot be parallelized it seems :)

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't surprise me. However, should you be able to implement a simple routine for the intersection of ellipsoids in the plane, one can use `Compile` to turn it into a library that _can_ be called in a parallelized way. I have made quite good experiences with this way of parallelization.

Answer (score 4):

A circle with center at $p$ radius $r$ and orientation $\vec n$ normalized, can be represented as

$$
c_i \to \{p_i, r_i \vec n_i\}
$$
A circle

$$
c_0 \to \{p_0, r_0 \vec n_0\}
$$

can be drawn with the parametric

$$
p = p_0 + r_0 \vec e_1\cos\mu +r_0\vec e_2\sin\mu,\ \ \mu\in (0,2\pi]
$$

where $\vec n_0, \vec e_1, \vec e_2, $ form an orthonormal basis.

An ellipse can be drawn with the parametric

$$
p = p_0 + a_0 \vec e_1\cos\mu +b_0\vec e_2\sin\mu,\ \ \mu\in (0,2\pi]
$$

where $a_0, b_0$ are the main axes.

With those facts follow two modules: one which plot a circle **drawcircle** and other that giving two circles, draw the projection for a circle $\{p_1,r_1\vec n_1\}$ onto the plane defined by $\{p_2,\vec n_2\}$ **projection**

With those modules we can verify the projection overlapping. The overlapping area computation is not considered here.

NOTE

The projections are represented by dashed lines.

```
drawcircle[p_, n_, color_] := Module[{t1, t2, t3, tau, tau0, n0, v, gr1, gr2, equ1, equ2, equ3, sols, r},
r = Norm[n];
n0 = n/r;
tau = {t1, t2, t3};
equ1 = n0.tau == 0;
equ2 = tau.tau == 1;
equ3 = t1 + t2 + t3 == 0;
sols = Quiet@Solve[{equ1, equ2, equ3}, tau][[1]];
tau0 = tau /. sols;
v = Normalize[Cross[tau0, n]];
gr1 = ParametricPlot3D[p + r tau0 Cos[mu] + r v Sin[mu], {mu, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> color];
gr2 = Graphics3D[{Black, Arrow[{p, n + p}]}, Axes -> True, 
Boxed -> False];
Return[Show[gr1, gr2]]
]

projection[p1_, n1_, p2_, n2_, color_] := Module[{n10, n20, v1, v2, e1, e2, ex, ey, ez, equ1, equ2, equ3, sols,e20, p1p2, grep, axis, mu, r1, r2}, 
n10 = Normalize[n1];
r1 = Norm[n1];
r2 = Norm[n2];
n10 = n1/r1;
n20 = n2/r2;
v1 = (n10.n20) n20;
v2 = n10 - v1;
e1 = Normalize[v2];
e2 = {ex, ey, ez};
equ1 = e2.n2 == 0;
equ2 = e1.e2 == 0;
equ3 = e2.e2 == 1;
sols = Quiet@Solve[{equ1, equ2, equ3}, e2][[1]];
e20 = e2 /. sols;  
p1p2 = p1 - ((p1 - p2).n2) n2;
grep = ParametricPlot3D[p1p2 + r1 n1.n2 e1 Cos[t] + r1 e20 Sin[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, color}];
axis = ParametricPlot3D[(1 - mu) p1p2 + mu p1, {mu, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Dotted, Gray}];
Return[Show[grep, axis]]
]

p1 = {1/2, -1/2, 1/2};
p2 = {0, 0, 0};
n1 = Normalize[{1, 0, 1}];
n2 = Normalize[{0, 1, -1}];

c1 = drawcircle[p1, n1, Blue];
c2 = drawcircle[p2, n2, Red];
Show[c1, c2, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1]

pc1c2 = projection[p1, n1, p2, n2, Blue];
Show[c1, c2, pc1c2, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1]

pc2c1 = projection[p2, n2, p1, n1, Red];
Show[c1, c2, pc2c1, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems like it ought to work, but throws an exception right at the end. Building on the the example in the question, but with the length of the cylinders defined by a variable `len` that I can play with:

```
v1  = {0.5, 0.5, 0.5};
n1  = {1, 1, 1};
v2  = {1, 1.5, 0};
n2  = {1, 1, 0};
d   = 4;
len = 10;
```

Draw the cylinders and also a hperplane located at the origin of one of the cylinders.

```
cyl1 = Cylinder[{v1 - len*n1, v1 + len*n1}, d/2];
cyl2 = Cylinder[{v2 - len*n2, v2 + len*n2}, d/2];
hp   = Hyperplane[n1, v1];
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], cyl1, cyl2, hp}]
```

[image]

Now intersect them.

```
proj = RegionIntersection[Region@cyl1, Region@cyl2, Region@hp]
```

[image]

This is a proper region according to the test

```
RegionQ@proj
(* True *)
```

But it burps when I try to compute over it, using `RegionMeasure[ ]` or other methods.

```
RegionMeasure@proj
```

[image]

Comment: This is a bug and it were good if you could report it to support.

Comment: Small typo in the `cyl` definitions, they should be: `cyl1 = Cylinder[{v1 - len*n1, v1 + len*n1}, d/2]; cyl2 = Cylinder[{v2 - len*n2, v2 + len*n2}, d/2];` (now corrected in the OP too)

Comment: Updated to match...

Comment: @user21, bug reported.

Comment: FYI, Wolfram acknowledged the issue as a bug.

Answer (score -1):

To see the orthogonal projection, just make the disks into cylinders in turn. Most of the time the projection is going to be the empty set, though.

Comment: Apologies for being terse, I'm on mobile. Make disk 1 into a cylinder but leave disk 2 alone before using region intersect. Then change roles of disk 1 and disk 2.

Comment: Dear Dave, could you please kindly expand upon your answer when time allows. As it stands it is somewhat unclear and I'm not sure I've interpreted it correctly.

Comment: Nothing I tried panned out: geometric scene not set up for 3d, ellipses, or exact calculations. The projection onto a disc as you've described is going to be an ellipse that will almost certainly have an x y term. Wlig, let the disk being projected onto is the unit circle on the x y plane. Solving simultaneous non linear equations with the unit circle and the general ellipse surprisingly does give exact values for x and y. I didnt see any symmetry and see no obvious way to set up integrals to get an exact solution without case by case situations.