# Computing cross section area between cylinder and disk

Tags: regions, computational-geometry

I am creating a cylinder, whose center disk is placed at position vector `v1` and whose orientation is given by the disk's normal vector `n1.` The second object is a disk, embedded in the same box, but since I don't know how to draw disks in $3D$ in Mathematica, I use a very thin cylinder to approximate the disk, which is placed at `v2` and orientation `n2.` Both have diameter `d=4.` Here's the setup:

```
v1 = {0.5, 0.5, 0.5};
n1 = {1, 1, 1};
v2 = {1, 1.5, 0};
n2 = {1, 1, 0};
d = 4;

ef1 = 5; (*elongation factor of cylinder 1 to find endpoints to draw*)
\
ef2 = 0.00001; (*elongation factor of cylinder 2, to approximate disk*)
\
cyl1 = Cylinder[{v1 - ef1*n1, v1 + ef1*n1}, d/2];
cyl2 = Cylinder[{v2 - ef2*n2, v2 + ef2*n2}, d/2];
```

And drawn together: `Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], cyl1, cyl2}]`:

[image]

As we see in the image, the cylinder is crossing a portion of the disk, and I'm trying to learn if:

- Is there way a to compute the area of the disk that is in intersection with the crossing cylinder? A naive approach using `Area@RegionIntersection[cyl1, cyl2]` seems not to work (returns `Undefined`).

Comment: If the axes of the cylinders are given by `n1, n2` you should correct your formulas to `cyl1 = Cylinder[{v1 - ef1*n1, v1 + ef1*n1}, d/2];cyl2 = Cylinder[{v2 - ef2*n2, v2 + ef2*n2}, d/2];`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Done, thanks for spotting the typo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You consider tw0 3D-regions, that's why its onlye possible to calculate a volume!

Try

```
dV=Volume@RegionIntersection[cyl1, cyl2]
(*0.000249282 *)
```

To get an approximation of the disk area divison by the thickness of your pseudo-disc gives the result!

**addendum**
The workaround `cyl2` isn't necessary. Try

```
disk = ImplicitRegion[({x, y, z} - v2).n2 == 0&&Norm[{x, y, z} - v2] <= d/2, {x, y, z}]
dA = RegionIntersection[cyl1, disk] 
Area@dA        
(*8.81346*)
```

Comment: Ah indeed, that makes sense now! By the way, didn't you mean to write `RegionIntersection` instead of `RegionDifference`? Computationally, is my approach with pseudo-discs as defined here a bit of overkill for estimating the intersection?

Comment: You're right, I modified my answer!

Comment: Many thanks! In case you are interested, this question originated from discussions [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/210260/52181).

Comment: You're welcome, I'll have a look at the link.

Comment: Dear Ulrich, do you reckon our approach (using RegionIntersection) could be sped up if we didn't create the cylinder as we do currently, and instead used e.g. an implicit definition of it? I mean I assume `RegionIntersection` is the bottleneck here and it performs slower the larger `ef1` is.

Comment: @user929304 I'm not sure about improvement, because finally `RegionIntersection` is necessary. The "implicit cylinder" `ImplicitRegion[-ef1 <= Norm[n2 n2.({x, y, z} - v1)/n2.n2] <= ef1 &&Norm[{x, y, z} - v1 - n2 n2.({x, y, z} - v1)/n2.n2] <= d/2,{x, y, z}]`

Comment: indeed your hunch was right: the implicit region makes it even slower!